# How to build all modules from a certain aggregator project and all dependencies of those modules?

Tags: maven, maven-3

With Maven, I can specify a list of projects to build (-pl) and indicate that dependencies of the listed projects should also be build (-am), for example:

mvn install -pl exampleGroup:exampleArtifactId -am

Is there a way to specify that the projects to build should be all projects given an aggregator pom? I have tried to enter the aggregator project as -pl option, but this doesn't seem to build the configured modules at all.

Example:

exampleGroup:A has:

```
<modules>
    <module>B</module>
    <module>C</module>
</modules>
```

exampleGroup:B has:

```
<modules>
    <module>D</module>
    <module>E</module>
</modules>
```

Now I want to build both D and E and their dependencies. So if there is a dependency from D or E to C, I would like to build all modules. If there is no dependency, then only D and E should be build.

Comment: Is that an aggregator or a multi module build? Those two have different purposes.

Comment: The Maven POM reference seems to use them as synonyms. Could you explain the difference? What I'm referring to is a pom file that only configures a certain set of modules to build.

Comment: Do thos modules have a parent which is referencing your root pom which you are describing? If you having dependencies have you defined them in the childs?

Comment: Module A and module B do not have parents. C, D, and E define their own dependencies, but they share a parent that uses dependencyManagement to define versions for common used dependencies.